# How to install Magento 2 on Xampp in Windows7

Tags: php, windows-7, installation, xampp, magento2

I have downloaded composer and magento2 from git hub. I have also Executed the command “composer install”. And then I am installing magento 2 on my localhost in windows 7 system using Xampp, but unable to install getting error in Step 1 : Readiness Check 
Error Getting "File Permission Check Server Failed to respond. Please try again".
I have googled a lot.After long search, I have found a link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1891, but here,there is no exact solution for Magento2 Installation on Xampp in Windows 7. If any one knows about this issue, Please reply back.

Comment: Can you provide a magento2 source code link which you have donwnload ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove last "/" in url and click on next.

I have same problem and i have remove "/" it's worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I switched to **php7** and it works now!